# Remainders of Java 9: alternatives and lib directories

Tags: java, openjdk, update-alternatives

I had the Java 9 JDK (`openjdk-9-jdk`) installed, but purged it again and also ran `apt autoremove --purge` afterwards. Now only the Java 8 JDK (`openjdk-8-jdk`) is installed.

However, there are still remainders:

- Some alternatives still point to non-existent Java 9 files:

  ```
  $ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep java-9
  jjs                            auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs
  keytool                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
  orbd                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/orbd
  pack200                        auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200
  rmid                           auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid
  rmiregistry                    auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry
  servertool                     auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/servertool
  tnameserv                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/tnameserv
  unpack200                      auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200
  ```

  There are no other alternatives in those link groups, so I can't reconfigure them, all return the same output (with respective alternative name):

  ```
  $ update-alternatives --config unpack200 
  update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/unpack200 is dangling; it will be updated with best choice
  There is only one alternative in link group unpack200 (providing /usr/bin/unpack200): /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200
  Nothing to configure.
  ```

  Can I simply delete those alternatives safely if they have no candidates?
- There is one file inside `/usr/lib` remaining:

  ```
  $ ls -lh /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/server/classes.jsa 
  -r--r--r-- 1 root root 18M Mai  8 22:30 /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/server/classes.jsa
  ```

  It is not part of any package (`dpkg -S FILENAME` returns nothing), so can I safely remove it?